# file input tag not opening file browser/camera very first time on https

Tags: javascript, html, input, camera, html5-video

I am developing a sample mobile web app to invoke camera. Please see below HTML and JS code to trigger file input click event with button onClick.

```
<input type="button" id="my-button" value="Capture"  onClick="openCamera()">

function openCamera(){
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
    input.setAttribute('capture', 'camera');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.click(); 
}
```

However this code is working fine, when I host my page on http server like

```
http://localhost(ipaddress to access via mobile browser)/PhotoLocker/index.html
```

but not with https url

```
https://localhost(ipaddress to access via mobile browser)/PhotoLocker/index.html
```

Interestingly, even with `https://`, it is working from 2nd time on wards.

**Note**: No Allow/Block Camera permission dialog is eating the first click event, since I don't see any Camera permission dialog. Testing on Chrome V64 on Nexus6 Android device.

I know, dynamically created input element click must be called in some other button click.

Can someone help me understand, why very first time on https:// camera/file browser option not coming ?

**Resolution**:
If somebody is struggling with similar issue, this might help.
This issue is nothing to do with https. In my library some internal methods will only fire on https are trying to access mediastream where the original button click event is interrupted. I made fix in my library.

Comment: Why do you need to create a new `input` ? Why don't you use `#my-button` ?

Comment: @SergeK. I don't want to expose file input control to application user. I do the styling for button and behind the scenes - I will invoke camera with file input.

Comment: But you can also style file input, can't you ?

Comment: @SergeK. Hmm.. You can think openCamera() method is part of separate library and Application user is calling it in some button click.

Comment: Alright. I made it a snippet and it seemed to work though SO snippets are loaded via https. Are you sure there is no error/conflict ?

Comment: @SergeK. Yes in straight away calling openCamera() in simple snippets is working fine even in https. But the way my photo library is dealing with the same code scattered in multiple places and needs several callback to reach input.click() line. After 2 days struggle, I found that one of the internal  chaining methods is trying to access MediaStream and it is eating away first click. Tx for your time.